# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+bi})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a-bi})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

For $a,b,n\in\mathbb{Z}$:

- Do we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+bi})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a-bi})$?
- More generally, do we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a+bi})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a-bi})$?
- Given $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+bi})$, does there always exist a Gaussian Prime $z$ so that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+bi})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{z})$?

Comment: You're interested in $b\ne0$ and $n>0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over a field $K$ of characteristic zero, $K(\sqrt\alpha)=K(\sqrt\beta)$
for non-squares $\alpha$ and $\beta$ iff $\alpha\beta$ is a square in $K$.

Here, take $K=\Bbb Q(i)$, $\alpha=a+bi$ and $\beta=a-bi$. Then $\alpha\beta=a^2+b^2$ and that is a square in $\Bbb Q(i)$ iff it's a square in
$\Bbb Q$. So, for instance, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2+i})\ne\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2-i})$.

Comment: In your example, what is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{(2+i)/5})$?

Comment: That is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2-i})$.

Comment: Does this mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2-i})$?

Comment: No${}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the proper subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2-i})$ are only $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, right? We also have $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2-i})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2-i})$ is not Galois over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: But we have $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\sqrt{2-i})/K) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.